# Angularjs confirm dialog modal on top of modal

Tags: angularjs

I am using Bootstrap modal. I am currently showing some information in a modal. If the user clicks `Cancel` on the modal, I want to show a confirmation modal on top of it. How can I achieve this?

Here is my sample code:

```
angular.module('modalApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

    $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

    $scope.open = function (size) {

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'templates/myModalContent.html',
            controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
            size: size,
            resolve: {
                items: function () {
                    return $scope.items;
                }
            }
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
            $scope.selected = selectedItem;
        }, function () {
            $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });
    };
};


var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

    $scope.items = items;
    $scope.selected = {
        item: $scope.items[0]
    };

    $scope.ok = function () {
        $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        if(confirm('Do you want to continue')) {
            alert('ok');
        } else {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        }

    };
};
```

In the place of Javascript confirm, I want to show another bootstrap modal confirm.

Comment: Just call $modal.open(.....) where you have call to confirm() and a new modal should open. Have you tried that ?

Comment: I think the easiest solution would be a simple show/hide within your existing modal.

Comment: So... is that the answer then?